# c# windows form override dispose issue

Tags: c#, dispose, j#

I'm working on a projact where i convert j# UI code to C#.
in the old code (j#) there was a class extends Form, and method:

```
public void dispose()
{
   super.dispose();
   components.dispose(); 
}
```

after changing the imports from: `com.ms.wfc.ui` to `system.windows.form` the compiler is asking me to
change `super.dispose()` to `super.Dispose()`. (same with component).

My question is if i need to change the method above to `Dispose` as well?
in the J# code it doesnt say if this is override or not, and i think if i dont change it, `dispose()` will not be call whan this form is close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare the Dispose method as override, it's enough if you change it to Dispose().

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Perform any object clean up here.

        // If you are inheriting from another class that
        // also implements IDisposable, don't forget to
        // call base.Dispose() as well.
    }
}
```

Here is a good tutorial on using Dispose in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P

Answer (score 1):

C# is case-sensitive. And if you want to override the IDIsposable interface method implementation of the form, you must write is with the capital letter:

```
public void Dispose()
{
   //...
}
```

Hope, I understood your problem correctly...